# Select distinct values from a text column in PgAdmin

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using pgAdmin4 I imported text files to a table with 13 columns.  The table columns are all of type text.  The first column, named Date, contains text of dates (YYYY-MM-DD).  There are multiple rows per date.  I want to query and show the unique dates.  I have used the following query from pgAdmin:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'Date'
FROM "myTable"
```

The result from this query is just 1 result: Date.  It does not include any data from a given cell.

[image]

I would expect the result to show:

```
2020-01-16
2020-01-15
2020-01-14
```

To try a simpler query.  I queried:

```
SELECT 'Date'
FROM "myTable"
```

The query returns every row, but instead of the data (YYYY-MM-DD), each cell just says Date.

In following [this PostgreSQL Tutorial](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-select-distinct/) I could not replicate the results.

I have noticed that with pgAdmin queries I wrap my columns and tables in single, or double quotes, whereas quotations are not included in many tutorials.

Comment: 'Date' is a string literal.

Comment: You select a text literal `'Date'` instead of a field named `"Date"`. Pay attention to quotes type used.

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) single quotes are for strings. So `'Date'`  is a string **constant** - columns should be enclosed in double quotes. Or better: not quoted at all

Comment: SIngle quotes define a string, not a reference to a column.  This is a common typo.

Comment: *Or better: not quoted at all* Depends on a field name. If a field was defined with dquotes it is case-sensitive and must be enclosed in a query.

Comment: Thank you.  The quote issue fixed the problem

Comment: ANSI SQL, Oracle and Teradata have `DATE` as reserved word. One reason to delimit it. (Or change it.)

Comment: I will change it.  Thank you

Comment: @Akina: you shouldn't create columns with quoted identifiers to begin with: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: @Akina I will change to proper format shortly.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the single quotes around `'Date'`, otherwise it's a string litteral, not a column name.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM myTable
```

If you really need to quote the identifier, for example if it matches a reserved word, if it contains special characters or if the column was declared as case-sensitive, then Postgres wants double quotes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "Date" FROM "myTable"
```

Comment: I would consider this to be a typo, and as such, you shouldn't answer it, but rather just vote to close.

Comment: ERROR:  column "date" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM "MyTable"
                        ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "MyTable.Date".
SQL state: 42703
Character: 17.   Do you know why this error would come up then?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I voted to close. I thought, however, that an explanation might be of interest, hence the answer.

Comment: Was definitely a quote issue.  Problem solved.  Thank you